# Modify Workflow of Incident Management accelerator in K2 Studio

Tags: workflow, k2

I am totally new to K2 and its very basic. I have installed the Incident Management accelerator. I am struggling hard to locate the workflow called “Incident Resolution” under the rules "when create button is clicked". I would like to modify this workflow to fit my purpose. Can anybody help to locate the workflow in K2 Studio? Any help on this is greatly appreciated.

Regards
George

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First let me tell that it is not obvious, so new or not to K2, your question is legit :) It is very easy to do... once you know :)

If you already installed the accelerator, I suppose you already unzipped the package and used the K2 Package and Deploy to install it on your server.

Your first stop will be the K2 Workspace. For this, you **must** use Internet Explorer. The URL will usually be http://yourserver:81/Workspace
On your system, the port may differ dependending on your installation.

In the workspace, go to `Management/Management` console.
Expand your server then go to `Workflow Server/Processes/Operations/Incident Resolution/Versions`

By default, you should see a single version. Notice the **download** link next to the version. It allows you to download the process.
Download the process and save it somewhere. You will get a self-exctratible zip (.exe). Run that .exe and choose where the process should be extracted. It can be anywhere.

Browse to this location on your file system.

Double click the .k2proj project file. This will open the project containing the process using **K2 Studio**.

From here, you can now modify the process and **deploy** a new version on the server.

Please note, that at any time, if your new process ends up being 'not that good', you can go back to the **versions** screen in order to set another version of the process as the default one (the one that will be opened by the SmartForms). That gives you them time to fix your process and deploy a new version of the process that works better.

Let me know how it goes.